# How to add line break to a rtl string in strings.xml in Android?

Tags: android, xml, line-breaks, right-to-left, hebrew

I'm trying to translate my android app from English to Hebrew by adding a `strings.xml` file to values directory and translating all English strings.

My problem is that adding a line break (`\n`) to the Hebrew string as i do with my English `strings.xml` strings doesn't work. An example to an English string with a line break:

```
<string name="no_group_instructions">You don\'t have a group yet!\n\nPlease choose whether to create a new group, or to join an existing one...</string>
```

How can i add line breaks to my non-English strings?

**EDIT**

I eventually did manage to do the line break in the Hebrew string using \n.
I guess that the right-to-left writing, which is not supported well enough in Android Studio, caused the problem in the first place. I solved it by copying the string with the \n's from notepad straight to the strings.xml file, and not wrote it directly in the Android Studio.

Comment: they are the same `\n` where do they not work?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. To solve it, just copy-paste "\n" into your string as I did:

`<string name="ta_tv_button_text">?היוםn\אכלתn\מה</string>`

Make sure you support RTL in both your manifest and the TextView.

I could not copy-paste my string into here (it mixed up the string). I believe it will mix it up again if you try to copy-paste it to your project, so do not copy-paste my string to your project. This is how the string looks like in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `<br />` to break line in xml instead of `\n` for example :

```
<string name="no_group_instructions">You don\'t have a group yet!
<br/><br/>Please choose whether to create a new group, or to join an existing one...
</string>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Tried with English first and it doesn't work - the two sentences are just being merged.

Comment: @milyoav i get that result in the picture, so it break the line, how it does not work with you, what you try to do?

Comment: I don't understand. Your picture shows the code and not the screen itself. When i'm adding the <br/> tag instead of the \n it being interpreted as a space instead of a line break...

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool way to do this, at runtime.

```
 <string name="title">Testing%sNew Line, stand back!</string>
```

> %s is a string , and be replaced.

Then get it by resources `String word = String.format(Locale.English,getString(R.string.title),"\n")`; 
It will load the string then replace then `%s` with `\n`

Comment: oh, choose your own Locale by the way

Comment: Thanks @Remario but i'm looking for a way to do this in the strings.xml file.

Comment: but at the end of the day, u just want the string should not matter really

Answer (score 0):

use a blackslash not a forwardslash. "\n"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Hello\nWorld!</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: you put "\n" in a string in the xml file, it's taken as "\\n"

So , I did : text = text.Replace("\\n", "\n"); ( text is taken from resX file)

And then I get a line jump on the screen

Comment: the \n works just fine on English strings. My problem is when trying using \n on Hebrew strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String formattedText = getString(R.string.no_group_instructions); 
Spanned result = Html.fromHtml(formattedText); 
view.setText(result);
```

Comment: Use the Html. FromHtml () can take the string formatting into Html code, this will have a role in the \ n.

Comment: Thanks, can you please edit the question and add the info.